# Symplectic group and Quaternion Inner product

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, quaternions, symplectic-linear-algebra

I have a problem understanding a passage from "Naive Lie theory"(by John Stillwell), here is the passage from section $3.9$ ,page $71$:

> The idea of treating orthogonal, unitary, and symplectic groups uniformly
>   as generalized isometry groups of the spaces $R^n$, $C^n$, and $H^n$ seems to
>   be due to Chevalley [1946]. Before the appearance of Chevalley’s book,
>   the symplectic group $Sp(n)$ was generally viewed as the group of unitary
>   transformations of $C^{2n}$ that preserve the symplectic form:
>
> \begin{equation}
> (\alpha_1 \bar\alpha'{_1}-\beta_1 \bar\beta'{_1})+ ...+(\alpha_n \bar\alpha'{_n}-\beta_n \bar\beta'{_n}) 
> \end{equation}
>
> where $(α_1,β_1, . . . ,α_n,β_n)$ is the typical element of $C^{2n}$. This element corresponds to the element $(q_1, . . . ,q_n)$ of $H^n$, where:
>
> \begin{equation}
> q_i=\begin{bmatrix}
>     \alpha_i & -\beta_i  \\
>     \bar\beta_i & \bar\alpha_i 
>    \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation}
>
> The invariance of the quaternion inner product:
>
> \begin{equation}
> q_1 \bar{q}'{_1}+...+q_n \bar{q}'{_n}
> \end{equation}
>   is therefore equivalent to the invariance of the matrix product:
>
> \begin{equation}
>  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> \alpha_1 & -\beta_1\\
> \bar{\beta_1} & \bar{\alpha_1}\end{array} \right)\
>  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}\
> \bar{\alpha'_1} & \beta'_1\\
> -\bar{\beta'_1} & \alpha'_1\end{array} \right)+...+
> \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> \alpha_n & -\beta_n\\
> \bar{\beta_n} & \bar{\alpha_n}\end{array} \right)\
>  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}\
> \bar{\alpha'_n} & \beta'_n\\
> -\bar{\beta'_n} & \alpha'_n\end{array} \right)
> \end{equation}
>
> which turns out to be equivalent to the invariance of the symplectic form.

My problem is that i couldn't see how the invariance of matrix product results in invariance of symplectic form mentioned by the author. I have checked the Chevalley book but i didn't find the specific symplectic form used by Stillwell.
Chevalley and other authors have used a symplectic form that doesn't include complex conjugate. This free complex conjugate symplectic form makes sense because it is the off-diagonal element of matrix product above, .i.e:

\begin{equation}
(\alpha_1 \beta'{_1}-\beta_1 \alpha'{_1})+ ...+(\alpha_n \beta'{_n}-\beta_n \alpha'{_n}) 
\end{equation}

Other authors also use symplectic form without complex conjugate, for example

[Modern Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZEn0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&dq=%22sp(n)%22+%22u(2n)%22+preserves+symplectic+form+complex&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBmoVChMIiqWvpeaFxwIVBv1yCh0lfQ-m#v=onepage&q=%22sp(n)%22%20%22u(2n)%22%20preserves%20symplectic%20form%20complex&f=false)

[Modern Geometric Structures and Fields](https://books.google.com/books?id=wRMPCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&dq=%22sp(n)%22+%22u(2n)%22+preserves+symplectic+form+complex&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAjgKahUKEwiBmLaf54XHAhUD3iwKHYlZBp4#v=onepage&q=%22sp(n)%22%20%22u(2n)%22%20preserves%20symplectic%20form%20complex&f=false)

But i don't know how to see the symplectic form defined by Stillwell is remained invariant.

What am i missing?

Comment: Notice that: 

$$q_1 \bar{q}'{_1}= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha_1 & -\beta_1\\
\bar{\beta_1} & \bar{\alpha_1}\end{array} \right)\
\overline{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\
\alpha'_1 & -\beta'_1\\
\bar{\beta'_1} & \bar{\alpha'_1}\end{array} \right)}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha_1 & -\beta_1\\
\bar{\beta_1} & \bar{\alpha_1}\end{array} \right)\
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\
\bar{\alpha}'_1 & -\bar{\beta}'_1\\
\beta'_1 & \alpha'_1\end{array} \right)$$

however I do not know if I understand correctly your mean by $\bar{A}$.

Comment: I think $\bar{A}$ means quaternion conjugate(not just complex conjugate), because it's a quaternion inner product , notice that if we had a one dimensional space, i.e. $H$, then $q_1 \bar{q_1}$ should give the quaternion norm(which is$\alpha \bar{\alpha}+\beta \bar{\beta}$) on diagonal elements and zero on off-diagonal elements, the $\bar$ over a complex number is complex conjugate and a $\bar$ over a quaternion is quaternion conjugate.

Comment: The $\bar{q}$ is defined on page 58 of "Naive Lie Theory" in the same way that i used it here,

Answer (score 2):

Ok, It seems that my doubt was correct. The from without conjugates is invariant and it is a mistake in book. Probably will be corrected in new editions. It is weird to answer your own question, but since this question doesn't need to be open anymore, I do it :),